Does Riemann sum converge uniformly?
$f$ is a continuous function defined on [0,1].
$F_{n}$ is defined as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x}{n} f(\frac{ix}{n})$.

It's not too difficult to see that $F_{n}(x)$ converges to $F =\int_{0}^{x} f$, but how do you prove it does so uniformly? I know it has something to do with uniform continuity of $F$, but I'm having difficulty proving it.

What is your usual definition of the integral? The Darboux integral?

@Malady The Riemann integral

It follows by uniform continuity of $f$ (not that of $F$)

The argument for $f$ uniformly continuous is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452862/when-does-a-riemann-sum-converge-uniformly?rq=1 additionally the link includes a Dini argument.
